# opening/reading a text file in c

Tags: c, file, struct, fread

Hello i am running this C program on linux using gcc -Wall -std=c99 and a./out. I do not get any warnings/errors. But when i print my information read from a file i get crazy outputs. the file contains:

```
A13
B99
C2
D2
E44
F32
G2
H9
```

and the output is:

```
id:  A
size: 171522370
id:  C
size: 876939826
id:  4
size: 843516466
```

code is

```
typedef struct record{

    char id;
    int size;

}record; 


int main ()
{

   record reg;

    FILE *fp = NULL;


    fp = fopen("idSize.txt", "r");


    if ((fp = fopen("idSize.txt", "r")) == NULL){
      printf("error opening file");
      exit(1);
    }

    fread(&reg, sizeof(reg),1,fp);

    while (!feof(fp)){

        printf("id:  %c\n", reg.id);
    printf("size: %d\n", reg.size);


    fread(&reg, sizeof(reg),1,fp);

    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;

}
```

any help would be very appreciated! thanks a lott

Comment: If you'd like some help, please put some effort into formatting your code so it's easy to read.  Make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a total mess.  Is the file text or binary, because you are coding it as if you were reading a byte stream into a structure.  Maybe you mean to use fscanf instead?

Answer (score 3):

Your `fread` is reading *binary* information from the file rather than the *text* that it actually contains. B y that, I mean it expects to find the *memory image* of your structure in the file, which depends on your implementation.

So, for instance (though this all varies based on your implementation's padding behaviour and type sizes), it may be expecting a single-byte `char` followed by three padding bytes, followed by the four-byte binary representation of an `int`.

You should look into using `fscanf` instead, which can convert for you. By way of example, the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct record {
    char id;
    int size;
} record;

int main (void) {
    record reg;
    FILE *fp;

    if ((fp = fopen ("idSize.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
      printf ("Error opening file\n");
      return 1;
    }

    while (fscanf (fp, "%c%d\n", &(reg.id), &(reg.size)) == 2)
        printf ("id: %c, size: %d\n", reg.id, reg.size);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

produces:

```
id: A, size: 13
id: B, size: 99
id: C, size: 2
id: D, size: 2
id: E, size: 44
id: F, size: 32
id: G, size: 2
id: H, size: 9
```